# NSXMLParser response time

Tags: ios, parsing, nsxmlparser

How could i obtain the response time of parser request ?

```
NSString *connString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:connString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

parserUserData = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[parserUserData setDelegate:self];
```

I used the following example but it didn't return a response time, just the response.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"response: %@", string);
}
```

Comment: Do you want the amount of time elapsed requesting the data or parsing or both? You have to calculate this yourself. For example, if you're looking for elapsed time, do `CFAbsoluteTime start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();` before the request, and then `CFTimeInterval elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start;` at the end. That will give you the number of seconds that `elapsed`. If this is what you're looking for, I'll post this as an answer. If not, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the parsing happens synchronously, you can just capture the start time before parsing and then calculate the elapsed time when done:

```
CFAbsoluteTime start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

NSString *connString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:connString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

CFTimeInterval elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start;

NSLog(@"dataWithContentsOfURL elapsed time: %.3f", elapsed);

parserUserData = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[parserUserData setDelegate:self];

[parserUserData parse];

elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start;

NSLog(@"dataWithContentsOfURL & parse elapsed time: %.3f", elapsed);
```